# Reflected XSS in the url path

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat7, xss

I'm trying to fix a reflected XSS attack, which is injected in the path url something like this : http:/dev.app.com/Service/form//%27%7Calert(document.domain)%7C%27?method=Init

I tried XSSFilter with ESAPI (for encoding), which partly solved the issue. I would like to know if we can prevent the attack with Tomcat relaxedPathChars='[]' configuration.

I tried configuring relaxedPathChars='[]' but no luck, I'm running this on a Tomcat 7.0.56

`<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" relaxedQueryChars='[]^' relaxedPathChars='[|]'/>`

(Application is running only on AJP protocol)